# How to sync a GitHub Repository with a hosted website

Tags: github

Please forgive me, I have never worked with GitHub and it may be that the question is very lame.

- I have a homepage on a Linux machine at `www.example.com` in the
  folder `/var/www/homepage`.
- And I have a GitHub account where I have a repository where I have
  created a project called "homepage".

I develop the page offline on my computer and upload it to GitHub using various tools that push and pull to GitHub. This works pretty well with VS Code as well as Notepad++ and Plugin. I also plan to work with other developers on this homepage.

*Now comes the question:* ...

- I want to sync the GitHub repository with the homepage so that the GitHub starts the update on the homepage. And in the future my team members can also update the homepage. The projects are private of course and so I assume I need a Linux client running on the homepage server. But this is not possible, because it is a hosted website.
- If for some reason the code is changed on the web server, that should come as a push request to Github repository.

Comment: there is a extension called ftp-simple it has the `autosave` option